# VSCode's User Snippets Not Working for Markdown and Latex Files

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, markdown, vscode-snippets

I have gotten user snippets in VSCode to work for C and C++, but for some reason VSCode is not providing snippet suggestions for `.md` and `.tex` files.

Here is a minimal example of `tex.json` (that doesn't work):

```
{
    "dummy": {
        "prefix": "dummy",
        "body": [
            "some random text for demonstration"
        ],
        "description": "A dummy snippet"
    }
}
```

VSCode provides suggestions in `.md` and `.tex` files, just not user snippets. How do I fix this issue or employ some other way to use user snippets for Markdown and Latex?

**Update:** Snippets are now working in `.md` files, thanks to the comment by @Mark. I need to type the prefix and press `Ctrl + Space`. This solution does not, however, work for Latex.

Comment: It looks like you need to `Ctrl+space` for markdown at least, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1617 You do not get automatic suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

For markdown files try this language-specific setting in your `settings.json` file:

```
  "[markdown]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
      "other": true,
      "comments": true,
      "strings": true
    }
  }
```

and you shouldn't need to trigger the snippet suggestion with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> anymore.

[For latex files I don't need that setting - if snippets aren't working in your latex files try the same setting but with `latex`.]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes "Ctrl+ Space" is a shortcut for switching input methods on Windows, please turn it off, it works for me

Comment: How to turn it off?

Comment: @AdityaHarikrish Start -> Settings -> Devices -> Typing _(on left panel)_
-> Advanced keyboard settings _(link at the bottom of right section)_
-> Input language hot keys _(link)_.

Then change (or remove) key sequence in Windows classic window, if you have `CTRL + SPACE` for any from the list